# Change open / close text onclick

Tags: jquery, slide

Found a fiddle on stack, and played with it a tad to suit our needs.

But .. I need to the "tab" thats below the container div, to change text based on what state. ie. if open text should say close and vice versa and other element hidden.

I am guessing we should be able to add if else condition to js. Just a little stuck.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/zEcXp/

Code:js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div#panel").show();

var autoTimer = null;

autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
    }, 5000);
},2000);

$("#open").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
    if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
    autoTimer = null;
});

$("#close").click(function(){
    $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
    if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
    autoTimer = null;
});
```

});
code: html

```
<div id="widget">
 <div id="panel">Slidepanel<br />Slidepanel<br />Slidepanel</div>
  <div id="open">Open</div>
  <div id="close">Close</div>
</div>
```

code:css

```
#widget {position:relative;width:500px;height:100%;}
#panel{height:100px;background:#fafafa;border:1px solid #cccccc;z-index:1;}
#open {cursor:pointer;position:absolute;left:50%;
padding:0px 8px;
border-left:1px solid #cccccc;
border-right:1px solid #cccccc;
border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
border-top:1px solid #ffffff;
z-index:2;}
#open:hover ,#close:hover {color:#3399ff;}
#close {cursor:pointer;position:absolute;left:50%;bottom:0px;}
```

The code is very crude, I realise we can shortcut the css etc. But have done it this way so you can see the issue.
To recap, I am happy with the TAB position, just need to either show Open or Closed dependant on the Panel state. So only show Open tab and make it clickable if panel is closed and vice versa.

Cheers.

.ps just wondering if toggle would work better. But anyhoo.. lets fix this first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't really understand what your whole timer stuff was about, but here is a simple means of sliding open/closed the panel and changing the message text. I bind to the click event of a single element, `toggle_panel` and then use jQuery's [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) which handles hiding/showing the div. Finally I just do a simple check of the text inside slide_toggle. If it says 'Closed' then I change it to `Open`. Otherwise it must be `Closed.` This is called a ternary operator. If you want to be more clever you perhaps will want to check either the display state for determining text or storing the state using jQuery's [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method. I think this is the most straightforward for your use case though.

http://jsfiddle.net/X9Vn4/79/

```
$("div#panel").show();

$("#toggle_panel").click( function() {
    $('#panel').slideToggle();
    $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Closed' ? 'Open' : 'Closed');                    
});
```

Another solution based on the fact that checking div visibility is more secure than checking contents of html

```
$("#toggle_panel").click(function(){
    if ($("div#panel").is(':visible')) {
         $(this).html('Close');           
    }
    else {
         $(this).html('Open');                       
    }
    $("div#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
    autoTimer = null;
});
```

Comment: will check it out thanks. Its on a intro page and is there to show available options... brb will test fiddle thankyou

Comment: Yep works great http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/zEcXp/1/ Meant to say would prefer with timer

Comment: Changed the close open paramaters (text ) and not quite 100% http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/zEcXp/3/ Seemingly, you must open and close cpl of times before text shows. If div is expanded text should be close, if its contracted text should be open.. think I have done it right but not 100% sure

Comment: Was just wondering, the main container panel, can that be set at a minimum height ? say 100px and on page load it is say 400px high then on close it goes to 100px high ? driving me nuts this lol

Comment: That gets more complicated because you can no longer rely on the is:visible check. I would store the divs display state using jQuery's data object and then use `animate` to change the height.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6775/discussion-between-mrtsherman-and-422)

Answer (score 1):

The html need to be (of course the css should be moved to a style sheet):

```
<div id="panel">Slidepanel<br />Slidepanel<br />Slidepanel</div>
<div id="open" style="display:none;">Open</div>
<div id="close">Close</div>
```

The javascript should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#panel").show();

    var autoTimer = null;

    autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
        autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
        }, 5000);
    },2000);

    $("#open").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
        $("div#open").hide();
        $("div#close").show();
        if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
        autoTimer = null;
    });

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $("div#open").show();
        $("div#close").hide();
        if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
        autoTimer = null;
    });         
});
```

Here's a fiddle of it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/K37uz/

Comment: apology posted wrong fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/zEcXp/ Will check yours out thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your code. you can improve the code from here on

HTML

```
<div id="panel">Slidepanel<br />Slidepanel<br />Slidepanel</div>
<div id="openClose">Close</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#panel").show();

    var autoTimer = null;

    autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("div#panel").slideDown("slow");
        autoTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            $("div#panel").slideUp("slow");
        }, 5000);
    },2000);

    $("#openClose").click(function(){
        $("div#panel").toggle("slow");
        if($("#openClose").text()=="Close"){
            $("#openClose").text("Open");
        }
        else
            $("#openClose").text("Close");
        if(autoTimer) clearTimeout(autoTimer);
        autoTimer = null;
    });        
});
```